# Convert Javascript Alert to Tooltip

Tags: javascript, tooltip, alert

I have a button which triggers js function and shows an alert. I would like to show a tooltip instead of an alert when the button is clicked. Basically, the end of my function is like this

```
alert(outputConcat)
```

How do I change this so that a tooltip shows instead? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: write a function, call it something meaningful like `showTooltip`, then instead of `alert(outputConcat)`, you would `showTooltip(outputConcat)` - note: you won't be actually showing a tooltip, as a tooltip is traditionally shown on hover (browsers show the elements title attribute, for example on hover)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org)
If you get Popper and their other library [Tooltip.js](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html) you can easily create tooltips like so:

```
var tooltip = new Tooltip(myElement,{
    title: 'Tooltip text',
    position: 'left', //or right, top, bottom
    trigger: 'click'
});

function myFunction(){
    //Your code here
    tooltip.updateTitleContent('New tooltip text');
    tooltip.show();
}
```

This will show the tooltip at the end of the function, then when you click the element it will hide again